# Passing states to rendered components in react native application

Tags: react-native

I have a react native application which has a swipebar added to the app.js file.
I need to add a menu button on all/some pages , on click which would show menu of the swipebar. However I am not able to call the method or state of the swipebbar from within individual components which are rendered.

App.js file

```
    <SideMenu
      menu={menu}
      isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
      onChange={isOpen => this.updateMenuState(isOpen)}
    >

      <Provider store={store}>

        <NavigationController />
      </Provider>
    </SideMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it redux and access through store.getState().yourReducer and update your redux from anywhere or even use store.subscribe to subscribe to store changes and then update the state whenever you want

Comment: but the state of SideMenu is not added to reducer. The store concept doesnt apply on states/props of sideMenu as it lies outside the Provider.

Comment: you can subscribe to the store using store.subscribe and then set a state in the parent and pass it to the sideMenu